# Dice game sticking with original score but looping successfully

Tags: c, function, srand

I am writing a program in C that will roll two dice and output the sum.
The game is easy enough and now I am incorporating a function and Looping so that a using will make several attempts. The problem is that the score never changes after the first attempt. So I know the function is working but somehow the loop is throwing things off. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>


//Function prototype
int RollScore(int , int);

main()
{
  int LoopCount;
  LoopCount = 0;

  for(LoopCount = 0; LoopCount < 11; LoopCount ++)
  {


 //Declare Variables
  int DieOne,DieTwo,DiceScore;

  //  One and Two will be hidden only Score will be output  
  DieOne = 0;
  DieTwo = 0;
  DiceScore = 0;


  printf("\n\n\tTo win you need a score of 7 or 11.");
  printf("\n\n\tPress a key to Roll the Dice!");

  //Trigger Random number generator and remove previous text    
  getch();
  system("cls");

  DiceScore = RollScore(DieOne , DieTwo);

  //Create Condition to either show user a win/lose output
  if (DiceScore == 7 || DiceScore == 11)
    {
                printf("\n\n\n\t\tYou Rolled a score of %d" , DiceScore);
                printf("\n\n\n\t\tCongratulation! You win!");

                LoopCount = 11;
    }//end if
     else
         {
                  printf("\n\n\n\t\tYou Rolled a score of %d" , DiceScore);
                  printf("\n\n\n\t\tSorry you have lost! Thanks for playing!");                 
                  printf("\n\n\t %d Attempt!" , LoopCount);
         }//end else

  //Prevent the IDE from closing program upon termination
  getch();
  system("cls");

  }//End For




}

//Function definition
int RollScore (int Dieone , int Dietwo)
{
return (srand() % 5) + 1 , (srand() % 5) + 1;
}
```

Comment: Beginner. Made some effort. Used code formatting and English well enough. +1 for encouraging him.

Answer (score 1):

```
return (srand() % 5) + 1 , (srand() % 5) + 1;
```

Call `srand` once to seed the random number generator and then call `rand` to get a random number.

[Basic rand function documentation with an example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/).

Comment: So it should look : return (srand() % 5) + 1 , (rand() % 5) + 1;??

Comment: And by once, ouah means once in the entire program (at the beginning), not every time you call `rand`.

Comment: @Ev00 No, you shouldn't use a comma, the comma there means that the first expression is evaluated and its value is ignored, then the value of the expression after the comma is returned you should use a `+` there. And `% 6` instead of `% 5`.

Answer (score 0):

srand() is used to initialize seed of a random numbers generator , rand() is the function that actually returns random number so you need to call srand() once before the for loop,

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to get a value between 1 and 6 you have to do something like `srand() % 6 + 1`. Modulo 5 yields a value between 0 and 4, adding 1 you'll get a number between 1 and 5, 6 will never come out.
Second you want to return the sum of two num, you only return the value of the second draw. Try :

```
//Function definition
int RollScore (int Dieone , int Dietwo)
{
  return (srand() % 6) + 1 + (srand() % 6) + 1;
}
```

Don't forget to use pointers if you want the results of the draws ...

```
//Function definition
int RollScore (int *Dieone , int *Dietwo)
{
  *Dieone = srand() % 6 + 1;
  *Dietwo = srand() % 6 + 1;
  return *Dieone + *Dietwo;
}
```